# How to ORDER BY in Grails HQL statement

Tags: hibernate, grails, sql-order-by, hql

I have a relationship like this:

```
class Foo {
    static hasMany = [bars: Bar, things: Thing]
}

class Bar {
    // Has nothing to tie it back to Foo or Thing
}

class Thing {
    // Has nothing to tie it back to Foo or Bar
}
```

[image]

I have the following query with the following parameters, most of which are used for pagination with flexigrid.  This query gets all instance of `Thing` that are associated with a specific instance of `Bar` via `Foo`. So if my instance of `Bar` was `Bar1` would expect my query to return `Thing1` and `Thing2`:

```
def obj = Bar.get( 1 ) // Get Bar1
def max = params.int( "max" ) ?: 100 // Default max returned results is 100 unless otherwise specified
def offset = params.int( "offset" ) ?: 0 // Default offset is 0 unless otherwise specified
def sortname = params.sortname ?: "id" // Default is id, but could be any member of Thing that is not a "hasMany"
def sortorder = params.sortorder ?: "ASC" // Default is ASC, but could be DESC

def namedParams = [ obj: obj, max: max, offset: offset ]

Thing.executeQuery( "SELECT DISTINCT f.things FROM Foo f INNER JOIN f.things things INNER JOIN f.bars bars WHERE bars =:obj ORDER BY ${sortname} ${sortorder}", namedParams )
```

Hibernate does not allow the usage of named parameters to specify the `ORDER BY` clause, so I just interpolated the string.  The problem is that the results are not ordered as I have specified.  When using `ORDER BY id` Grails tells me `id` is ambiguous.

**Knowing that the variable `sortname` will always be a member of `Thing`, how can I specify what to sort on?**

Some of the things I have tried:

```
ORDER BY Thing.id // Fail
ORDER BY f.things.id // Fail
ORDER BY things.id // FAIL!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query should be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT thing FROM Foo f 
INNER JOIN f.things thing 
INNER JOIN f.bars bar 
WHERE bar = :obj 
ORDER BY thing.id
```

i.e. you should use the alias of the entity in the select clause instead of its path, and use the same alias in the order by clause.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for all your help. HQL isn't a vast departure from SQL, but it is just different enough to cause me some issues. I'm getting a good grip on it now though :)